# Binding to nested properties where observables in the chain can be null

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

I just read about KnockoutJS and when I try to bind to sub-properties on objects that can be null I get binding errors, e.g.:

```html
<div data-bind="text: selectedAccount().DocumentList().length"></div>
```

So once you call `ko.applyBindings` it tries to evaluate the above expression and if `selectedAccount` is null (which it is by default) it throws an error. I know that I can create a `dependentObservable` like so:

```
viewModel.docLength = ko.dependentObservable(function () { 
    return selectedAccount() ? selectedAccount().DocumentList().length : null;
})
```

But I was wondering if there's a solution other than putting properties in the ViewModel simply because I get a binding error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A couple thoughts:

If you don't want to bother with the dependentObservable, then you can place your statement directly in the text binding like:

```
<div data-bind="text: selectedAccount() ? selectedAccount().DocumentList().length : null"></div>
```

or even shorter:

```
<div data-bind="text: selectedAccount() && selectedAccount().DocumentList().length"></div>
```

Depending on your scenario, you can also use the template binding to your advantage when dealing with potentially null values.  It would be like this:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'accountTmpl', data: selectedAccount }"></div>

<script id="accountTmpl" type="text/html">
    ${DocumentList().length}
</script>
```

Additionally, in the 1.3 release of Knockout there will be some control flow bindings that could be helpful to you.  Particularly the "if" or "with" bindings would work for this situation.  They are described here:  https://groups.google.com/d/topic/knockoutjs/pa0cPkckvE8/discussion

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to put the null check responsibility on the framework? I guess it would require to split up the properties in the expression and subscribe to each tier.

Comment: The if/with bindings coming in 1.3 with do that null checking and quit trying to bind things, so there will be support in the framework soon.  I was mainly trying to show ways that you can do it in the current version of Knockout.